# Unable to record an upload file scenario in JMeter though it is possible by manual effort with specific browser settings

Tags: jmeter

I am working on upload file module that works on internet explorer only and it requires following browser setting mandatory:
"Include local directory path when uploading files to server" should be enabled.

A failure message "Unable to upload file" displays when we do not make required setting in browser while manual attempt else it works fine.

Now when I am trying to record the scenario in JMeter, getting same error message even I made required browser settings.

Note: Additionally, I tried to include these calls by copying from browser tools and paste it in JMeter transaction but get the same result in response.

Have any one experience the same or can help me out?

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider:

1. Make sure that you use Java implementation of HTTP Request
2. Make sure that "Use multipart/form-data for POST" is checked
3. Make sure that you provide a file within "Send Files With the Request" field providing correct path, parameter name and mime-type

If all above has already been applied and you still experience problems I would recommend to capture the data being sent by Internet Explorer with a sniffer (Fiddler, Wireshark, etc.) and compare it to data, being sent by JMeter. They must be the same. If they aren't - you'll need to customize it using HTTP Header Manager, HTTP Cookie Manager, etc. If JMeter is not flexible enough to set all the required parameters via GUI, i.e. still tries to send full path of file instead of just filename or vice versa, you can always go deeper and manually build multi-part post request via Java Request Sampler (see SleepTest and JavaTest source code for details) or via [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-functions) which is 100% compatible with Java syntax but may be harder to debug due to it's script nature.

Path to SleepTest and JavaTest files is follows:

```
/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java
/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java
```

JMeter sources are available from [JMeter download page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Comment: I still could not get the resolution to issue. On execeuting the request only file name is being sent instead of full file path.
Can you please elaborate how to use these Java test files/Java Request Sampler. Can we use Raw Request Sampler?
Note: These requests are https calls.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to upload the image using jmeter:

1. locate the image in bin folder Select Post method and check the "Use
   multipart/form-data for POST" in HTTP Request
2. Provide details of Send files With the Request in HTTP Request
3. Record the Upload scenario and stop button in Jmeter (Image wouldn't upload while recording in Jmeter)
4. Now before running the script, Go to upload response and give the full path of image in "Send files with request field"
5. Now Run the script. You can able to see the image